I'm having trouble with solving this wave equation on the interval $[0, \pi]$
The wave equation is the follwing:
$U$$tt$$-$$c^2U$$xx$$=0$, $x\in[0, \pi]$
$U$$x$$(0,t)=0$, $U(\pi, t)=0$
$U(x,0)=0$, $U$$t$$(x,0)=-12c· cos(\frac{3}{2x})$
I began by expressing the solution in the form:

$U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$

and the equation becomes:

$X· T'' - c^2X''T=0$

So that:

$\frac{T''}{c^2T} = \frac{X''}{X} = -λ $

This gives us 2 ODEs:
$X''+λ X=0$
$T''+c^2λ T=0$
Using the boundary conditions, we get:

$X'(0) = 0$ , $X(\pi)=0$

which when combined with the 1st ODE, we get an eigenvalue problem:
$X''+λ X=0$
$X'(0) = 0$ , $X(\pi)=0$
The general solution to $X(x)$ is:

$X(x) = c$1$cos(\sqrt{λ}x) + c$2$sin(\sqrt{λ}x)$ [Note λ > 0]

Using these conditions, we get $c$2$=0$ and $c$1 as nonzero
But I really don't understand where I should go from here, or if everything I've gotten is wrong. I'm just really lost
Any help?
Many thanks
Edit: Using the other boundary condition, I find the eigenvalues

$λ$$n$ $= n^2$

So,

$X$$n$$(x) = cos(nx)$

$T$$n$$(t) = a$$n$$cos(nct) + b$$n$$sin(nct)$


Hence, the general solution to $U(x,t)$ is:

$\sum_{n=1}^{∞} [a$$n$$cos(nx)cos(nct)$ + $b$$n$$cos(nx)sin(nct)]$

Not sure how to use the initial values to obtain the coefficients here

The error is from $X'(\pi)=0$ which should be $X(0)=X(\pi)=0$ instead.

And from this you will naturally obtain $X=c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0\to\sqrt{\lambda}=n.$

@MathArt Thank you. I'm confused on how to find the coefficients now, any help?

If $X’(0)= X(\pi)  = 0$, your eigenfunctions are not $X = \sin(nx)$.
